# iOS Set Property After Delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to set a property after a delay?  Such as:

```
// Compiler hates this
[self performSelector:@selector(imageView.image) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:newImage] afterDelay:0.5];
```

Or do I have to create a new method to be a called to put the setting of the property in? The above seems so simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the [default](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) name of the setter for a property named `image` will be `setImage`.

```
[imageView performSelector:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:newImage] afterDelay:0.5];
```

When you do not set the setter method it will generate a method prefixed with `set` then camel cased and it will accept a parameter of its type.

Ex.

```
@property(assign) id object;
//becomes
-(id)object {...} // getter
-(void)setObject:(id)inObject {...} //setter
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, use `dispatch_after`. If you type `dispatch_after` and ask for code completion, you get three lines of boilerplate code and a place to put *your* actual code in a block. In that block, `imageView.image=` is legal. Don't forget to change the default delay time from 2 seconds (kind of a long delay!).

Comment: This was tremendously helpful to me.  Thanks, Matt.